# Spring JUnit not loading whole applicationContext from XML

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, sessionfactory

I have created a JUnit test in spring with next code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
     "classpath:*/WEB-INF/demo-servlet.xml"})
public class CrudTestJUnit extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests  {

    @Autowired 
    protected ShoppingCartDao shoppingCartDao; 

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){

    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        System.out.println("Evo beanvoa:" + Arrays.toString(context.getBeanDefinitionNames()));
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

In demo-servlet.xml i defined bean:

```
  <bean id="shoppingCartDao" class="com.it355.hibernatecrud.dao.impl.ShoppingCartDaoImpl"></bean>
```

When i run JUnit test i get this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'CrudTestJUnit': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.it355.hibernatecrud.dao.ShoppingCartDao CrudTestJUnit.shoppingCartDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.it355.hibernatecrud.dao.ShoppingCartDao] found for dependency:
```

When i delete shopping cart i get this from getBeanDefinitionNames():

```
    Evo beanvoa:[org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor, 
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor, 
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor, 
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor, 
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor, 
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor, 
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory, 
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]
```

Here is my full demo-servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!--Kako bi Hibernate mogao da se poveže na bazu podataka potrebno je kreirati sesiju. To radimo u sledećem
    zrnu-->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" >
            <!--Dodavanje path-a na kome se nalaze podešavanja za Hibernate -->
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <!-- Dodavanje path-a paketa u kome se nalaze entity fajlovi na osnovu kojih
        će Hibernate kreirati bazu i upisivati u nju-->
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.it355.hibernatecrud.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--Transakcija se dešava između baze i programa korišćenjem Transaction Managera koji definišemo ovde
    On koristi sesiju koju smo definisali iznad    -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="shoppingCartDao" class="com.it355.hibernatecrud.dao.impl.ShoppingCartDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
          class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.it355.hibernatecrud" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/" />
    <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <set>
                <bean class="com.it355.hibernatecrud.converter.IntegerToCategory" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Am i wrong in calling configuration file or some other thing? Is there someone who had the same issue.

Also in my configuration file i have component scan configured and my application works and loads beans without any problem but JUnit is making a problem.

Comment: I think you should either use @RunWith annotation or extend the Spring test class, not both, try to remove the extends part.

Comment: i am getting the same problem with or without extending Spring test class

Comment: Ok, it looks like the config should not be in WEB-INF, where it can nt bea easily accessible by unit tests, but rather in src/main/resources (or src/test/resources if test only) and then you can just have @ContextConfiguration(locations = "/demo-servlet.xml")

Comment: or rather in subdirectory of resources like 'spring-config' or so and then @ContextConfiguration(locations = "/spring-config/demo-servlet.xml")

Comment: It works when i put absolute path but not from any other directory. Maybe it is NetBeans problem or so.

Comment: Did you try to move the config file to src/main/resources?

Comment: Yes but still it didn't worked. I just solved it like this: @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
     "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/demo-servlet.xml"})

This is working. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your XML configuration file can't be found or loaded properly, thus you aren't able to do the injections properly.

I suggest just use classpath, if your XML configuration file is within your CLASSPATH there's no need to mention WEB-INF etc'. Like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:demo-servlet.xml")
public class CrudTestJUnit extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests  {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end i found out that Configuration from WEB-INF must be loaded like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/demo-servlet.xml"})
```